# Replacing a disk in RAID1 on a mac 10.8 system

Tags: macos, hard-drive, raid, osx-mountain-lion, raid-1

What is the proper and safest way for replacing one of the disks in a RAID 1 array (mirrored) on mountain lion?

Both disks are currently OK but one of those drives is much older than the other. Would it be best to just wait for it to die, or is it okay to simply swap it out with the newer disk? If it is swapped out will it simply rebuild on next boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to swap drive with new one. Install drive and follow following [Apple procedure](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3305?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Thank you! I was having difficulty finding that document.